# Is there a Windows XP equivalent to Gnome Do?

Tags: windows-xp, gnome-do

[Gnome Do](http://do.davebsd.com/) lets me run programs, search for files, perform application actions, 'microblog', queue music and search the web among other things via a search and select type interface operated from the keyboard. Is there a similar program for Windows XP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/#screenshots) pretty much does the exact same thing for Windows, and it's open source too

> Launchy is a free Windows and Linux utility designed to help you forget about your start menu, the icons on your desktop, and even your file manager.

[image]

Comment: Why would I *want* to forget about my file manager? A file manager is your friend.

Comment: well,i don't really agree on the "forget about your file manager",but it certainly does the job just fine :D

Comment: Cool. Launchy plus WinSplit Revolution means I never have to look at my desktop again.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at [Windows version](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Do_it_on_Windows)

Comment: I have to build it myself? Fail! :( Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Colibri, Launchy, Executor, SlickRun or even not too visualy stunning but damn configurable "Find and Run Robot" ...

i'm sure there is much more if you search further ... wait ... *15 secs* ... wikipedia is your friend:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_launchers

Answer (score 0):

Mighty Box looks & feels almost exactly the same, it needs a bit of work,
it's probably a GnomeDo fork

the site: http://mb.eyalw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page